# change uinavigation bar item position

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

How can i change `UINavigation` `barItem` position from `leftBarButtonItem` to  rightBarButtonItem with back function

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to create a custom `BarButtonItem` and set it to the right side, also you need to hide the default `BackBarButton`, so try some thing like this. Add below code inside `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
let btnForward = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
btnForward.setImage(UIImage(named: "forward_Arrow"), forState: .Normal)
btnForward.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnForward)     
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backItem
```

After that add this action method inside your `ViewController`

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks now if i want to implement the function "self.buttonAction(_:)" to be in one class in the project  how can we implement this

Comment: You can set selector like this `#selector(CustomClass.buttonAction(_:))`

Answer (score 1):

In ViewDidLoad write,

```
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, target: self, action: "buttonMethod")
rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

And it's function for pop up

```
 func buttonMethod() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```